# Why ItemCommand doesn't fired on My Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

please could anyone review my code and tell me what is the reason that itemCommand not getting fired on Buttons click.

```
<div class="">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate>
              <div id="header" style="background-color:red">

              </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
             <div class="bms-car-item">
              <div >
                 <image style="width:80px;height:60px" src="http://img2.netcarshow.com/Volkswagen-Golf_R32_2005_800x600_wallpaper_01.jpg"></image>
              </div>
              <div>
                  Car Type : <b>  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VehicleGroup") %> class or Similar </b>
              </div>
              <div>
                  Car Group: <b> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SupplierGroup") %></b>
              </div>
              <div>
                  Properties: 
                  <cp:CarProperties ID="CarPropertiesControl" runat="server" />
              </div>
              <div>
                  Price Before Voucher: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PriceCust.Price") %> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PriceCust.Currency") %>
              </div>
              <div>
                  Price per Rent:<b class="PricePlaceHolder"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PriceCust.Price") %> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PriceCust.Currency") %></b>
              </div>

                 <div>
                     <a href="#" onclick="return ShowTerms()" >Additional Info</a>
                     <a href="#">Options Included in Price</a>
                 </div>
                 <asp:HiddenField ID="Selected" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VehicleModelCode") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
            </div>
            <div> <asp:Button Text="Select" ID="SelectButtonNext" CommandName="Get" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VehicleModelCode") %>' /></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

And relevant code behind class

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            var state = SessionManager.GetReservationState();
            //Load All Car Groups    
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadCurrencies();

                LoadModels(state);

            }
            else
            {
                Repeater.DataBind();
            }

    }

    private void LoadModels(BmsReservationHelper state)
    {
        if (state != null)
        {

            var carModels = BmsFascade.BmsFascade.GetCarsAndPrices(state.PickUpLocationCode.Trim(), state.PickUpTime.ToString(), state.ReturnTime.ToString(), "", "", "", "");
            // TODO: Check what to do if BMS returning 0 cars avaliable ...

            this.Repeater.DataSource = carModels.VehicleModels;

            this.Repeater.DataBind();


            var groups = carModels.VehicleModels.GroupBy(m => m.SupplierGroup).Select(m => m.FirstOrDefault());
            foreach (var g in groups)
            {
                this.CarGroupsFilter.Items.Add(new ListItem(g.SupplierGroup, g.SupplierGroup));
            }

        }
    }

    private void LoadCurrencies()
    {
        this.CurrencyList.Items.Clear();

        // Load All Currencies 
        var list = BmsFascade.BmsFascade.GetCurrencies();
        foreach (var currencyPipe in list.ReturnValues)
        {
            string[] values = currencyPipe.Split('|');
            this.CurrencyList.Items.Add(new ListItem(values[1], values[0]));
        }
    }

    protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Bind Car properties strip to the repeater control
        if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
        {
            var model = e.Item.DataItem as BMSEntities.VehicleModelsBatchVehicleModel;

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                // Trying to rebing command properties here ... no luck :-(
                Button myButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("SelectButton");

                myButton.CommandName = "Get";
                myButton.CommandArgument = model.VehicleGroup;
            }      


            BMS_BmsCarProperties_BmsCarProperties carProps = e.Item.FindControl("CarPropertiesControl") as BMS_BmsCarProperties_BmsCarProperties;
            if (carProps != null)
            {

               // model.VehicleModelInfo.
                carProps.LoadDataInfo(model);
            }     
        }

    }
    protected void Repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.CommandArgument;
        Response.Write("fdsljknalsjndflkjasndflkjansdlkfjnasldkjnf");
    }
```

Comment: Don't rebind on postback, ie. remove the "else" clause from your page load method.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in Base Page ... DataBind() for whole page was called without !ISPosback.

Comment: You are amazing ! how did you get that?